# Xamarin Forms Binding Object with List in property

Tags: list, forms, xamarin, observablecollection, collectionview

I have the following class in my project

```
  public class ListagemVideos
    {

        public int codplaylist { get; set; }
        public string titulo { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }

    }

    public class PlayList
    {
        public int codplaylist { get; set; }
        public string playlist { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos> videos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos>();
    }
```

My XAML file

```
 <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaVideosCursos}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="titibold"
                                    FontSize="40"
                                    Text="{Binding playlist}" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily="titiregular"
                                    FontSize="20"
                                    Text="{Binding descricao}" />
                                <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackLayout Margin="10">
                                        <Label
                                            x:Name="lblvideorecente"
                                            FontFamily="titiregular"
                                            FontSize="20"
                                            Text="{Binding videos.titulo}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ScrollView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

ListaVideosCursos is the name of the ObservableCollection that receives the object's data, well my question and that of many from what I've seen around is how to bind the properties of the List video object (titulo, url, descricao) to my collectionview?

Comment: your inner `StackLayout` is bound to `Lista`, but there is no property named that in your model.  It appears that it should be `videos` instead.  If you fix that, then you can bind your inner template just using `{Binding titulo}`, etc

Comment: Thanks, it was an error in the example I put, I already corrected my example by deleting that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the source videos for the `StackLayout` to help `Label` to find the value of titulo property.

You could refer to the code below.

Xaml:

```
 <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding playLists}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                                FontFamily="titibold"
                                FontSize="40"
                                Text="{Binding playlist}" />
                    <Label
                                FontFamily="titiregular"
                                FontSize="20"
                                Text="{Binding descricao}" />
                    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Margin="10" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding videos}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label
                                        x:Name="lblvideorecente"
                                        FontFamily="titiregular"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        Text="{Binding  titulo}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ListagemVideosViewModel();

    }
}
public class ListagemVideosViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PlayList> playLists { get; set; }
    public ListagemVideosViewModel()
    {
        playLists = new ObservableCollection<PlayList>()
        {
            new PlayList(){ codplaylist=1, descricao="A", playlist="aa", videos=new ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos>(){ new ListagemVideos() {  codplaylist=1, descricao="A2", titulo= "a_titulo", url= "A_url" } }},
            new PlayList(){ codplaylist=2, descricao="B", playlist="bb", videos=new ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos>(){ new ListagemVideos() {  codplaylist=2, descricao="B2", titulo= "b_titulo", url= "B_url" } }}

        };
    }
}
public class ListagemVideos
{

    public int codplaylist { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }

}

public class PlayList
{
    public int codplaylist { get; set; }
    public string playlist { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos> videos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListagemVideos>();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly, I believe many will be helped by your answer.